# How to disable MFA delete on your S3 bucket through AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I understand how to enable MFA delete, however, I was wondering if you can disable it after you've enabled it? 
This is what I did to enable:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket bucket-name --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled,MFADelete=Enabled --mfa "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:mfa/root-account-mfa-device xxxxx"
```

I tried this to disable:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket bucket-name --versioning-configuration Status=Disabled,MFADelete=Disabled --mfa "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:mfa/root-account-mfa-device xxxx"
```

But I got the following error:

> An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the PutBucketVersioning operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema

Answer (score 3):

Based on what I have learned so far, the only way to disable 'MFA Delete' is by running the following on the AWS CLI:

**aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket** *{bucketname}* **--versioning-configuration "MFADelete=Disabled,Status=Suspended" --mfa "**{arn of mfa-device} *{current 6 digit code from MFA device}*"

Also, user must own the MFA device represented by the *{arn of mfa-device}*.

Comment: +1, I ran into this issue trying to do `MFADelete=Enabled,Status=Disabled` before seeing this answer and realizing I should've been using *Status=Suspended* instead of *Status=Disabled*.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly I've been stuck with the same issue, but when I gave precedence to {MFADelete} over versioning status it eventually worked fine.

aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket bucket_name --versioning-configuration **MFADelete=Disabled,Status=Enabled** --mfa "{arn of root-mfa-device} {current 6 digit code from MFA device}" --profile profile_name

PS: I've looked up some posts and found that schema could change based on the call/action.

Answer (score 0):

aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket rajeevbuckettest001 --versioning-configuration MFADelete=Disabled,Status=Enabled --mfa "arn:aws:iam::420337427158:mfa/AUTHY 548818"

Comment: This will work for you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).